# How to generate alert when clicking Submit button, only when the html form is full using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html form with many forms of elements. I need to generate the alert "Thank you for your time! Your details have been submitted!" once the submit button is clicked, only when the form is full. When the form is empty I do not want to see this message. So far I've been using onClick event. Can someone please help me on this (I'm trying to implement this using Javascript)

Here's the Javascript code and HTML body

```
<html>

<head>

<title>JS Validation for other types of form input fields</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function submitClick( ) //function shows message after submitting information

  {

  alert("Thank you for your time! Your details have been submitted!");

  }


  function formValidation ( )

  {

  flag = true;

  if (document.myForm.user_name.value == "" )

  {

  alert ( "Please fill in your Name!" );

  flag = false;

  }

  // Validate letters only as Name
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(document.myForm.user_name.value))

  {

  alert("Enter alphabetic characters as Name!");

  flag = false;

  }

  // Validate emails
 if (!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)* (\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.user_email.value))  //Regular expressions to validate email

 {

 alert("Enter Valid Email Address!");

 flag = false;

 }

 // Validate Phone number

 flag = true;

 if (document.myForm.user_phone.value == "" )

 {

 alert ( "Please fill in your Phone Number!" );

 flag = false;

 }


 if (!/^[0-9]*$/g.test(myForm.user_phone.value))

 {

 alert("Enter numeric values as Phone Number!");

 flag = false;

 }


 if ((document.myForm.userGender[0].checked == false) &&  (document.myForm.userGender[1].checked == false ) )

 {

 alert ( "Please select your gender!" );

 flag = false;

 }

 if (document.myForm.userAge.selectedIndex == 0 )

 {

 alert ( "Please select your Age from the drop-down list!" );

 flag=false;

 }

 if (document.myForm.termsAndConditions.checked == false )

 {

 alert ( "Please check the Terms and Conditions box!" );

 flag= false;

 }

 return flag;

 }

 </script>

 </head>

 <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

 <form name="myForm" method="post" onSubmit=" return formValidation( );">

 <h1>Please fill out your details below:</h1>

 <p>Name: <input type="text" name="user_name"></p>

 <p>Email: <input type="text" name="user_email"></p>

 <p>Phone: <input type="text" name="user_phone"></p>

 <p>Gender: <input type="radio" name="userGender" value="Male">Male

 &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="userGender" value="Female">Female</p>

 <p>Age:

 <select name="userAge">

 <option value="">Please select your age:</option>

 <option value="0-17 years">0-17 years</option>

 <option value="18-29 years">18-29 years</option>

 <option value="30-40 years">30-40 years</option>

<option value="40-64 years">40-64 years</option>

<option value="65+ years">65+ years</option>

</select>

<p>Please tick the checkbox if you agree with our Terms and Conditions:

<input type="checkbox" name="termsAndConditions" value="Yes"> Yes

<p><input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Details" onClick="submitClick( )"></p>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: aren't you being premature telling user it is sent...before it is confirmed on server? What happens if it doesn't actually get sent or there is a server side error? Also better to use submit event of form instead of button click...what if user submits by keyboard?

Comment: after all your validation is ok, then if the user click on submit and  if flag is true, display the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `onclick` event handler for the submit button. Just use the `onsubmit` event handler of the form like this:

```js
  function submitClick() {
    if (formValidation()) {
      alert("Thank you for your time! Your details have been submitted!");
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function formValidation() {
    flag = true;

    if (document.myForm.user_name.value == "") {
      alert("Please fill in your Name!");
      flag = false;
    }

    // Validate letters only as Name
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(document.myForm.user_name.value)) {
      alert("Enter alphabetic characters as Name!");
      flag = false;
    }

    // Validate emails
    if (!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)* (\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.user_email.value)) //Regular expressions to validate email
    {
      //alert("Enter Valid Email Address!");
      //flag = false;
    }

    // Validate Phone number
    if (document.myForm.user_phone.value == "") {
      alert("Please fill in your Phone Number!");
      flag = false;
    }

    if (!/^[0-9]*$/g.test(myForm.user_phone.value)) {
      alert("Enter numeric values as Phone Number!");
      flag = false;
    }

    if ((document.myForm.userGender[0].checked == false) && (document.myForm.userGender[1].checked == false)) {
      alert("Please select your gender!");
      flag = false;
    }

    if (document.myForm.userAge.selectedIndex == 0) {
      alert("Please select your Age from the drop-down list!");
      flag = false;
    }

    if (document.myForm.termsAndConditions.checked == false) {
      alert("Please check the Terms and Conditions box!");
      flag = false;
    }

    return flag;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

  <form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return submitClick();">

    <h1>Please fill out your details below:</h1>

    <p>Name:
      <input type="text" name="user_name">
    </p>

    <p>Email:
      <input type="text" name="user_email">
    </p>

    <p>Phone:
      <input type="text" name="user_phone">
    </p>

    <p>Gender:
      <input type="radio" name="userGender" value="Male">Male &nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="userGender" value="Female">Female</p>

    <p>Age:

      <select name="userAge">

        <option value="">Please select your age:</option>

        <option value="0-17 years">0-17 years</option>

        <option value="18-29 years">18-29 years</option>

        <option value="30-40 years">30-40 years</option>

        <option value="40-64 years">40-64 years</option>

        <option value="65+ years">65+ years</option>

      </select>

      <p>Please tick the checkbox if you agree with our Terms and Conditions:

        <input type="checkbox" name="termsAndConditions" value="Yes"> Yes

        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Details">
        </p>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**notes:**

- I commented out the e-mail check as it does not seem to work.
- Safe validation should be handled the other way around: You set flag to false and when everything is fine you set flag to true.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(formValidation())
{
    alert("Thank you for your time! Your details have been submitted!"); 
}
```

Put an `if` before your alert in `submitClick` method. That way alert will be shown only when validation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

just add to your submit click:

```
function submitClick( ) //function shows message after submitting information
{
  let flag = formValidation();
  if(flag)
  {
     alert("Thank you for your time! Your details have been submitted!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked well, when submitClick( ) is to be used as onsubmit event handler

Comment: Yes you could do that or call it from the `onClick=""` event which is the same...